# Dynamically change the width of a div in angular 6

Tags: css, angular6

I want to dynamically change the width of a div in angular 6. The page is designed by using flex. So, I need to add to give the width like
`width : 41vw;` But, `[ngStyle]="width: '41vw'"` is not working at all.

Comment: Did you try only style="width: 41vw;"? Or ngStyle without []?

Comment: @SaqibRaja 
Thanks for the comment. 
That works. But, the thing is I need to add a conditional style. and pass the width. For example,
If variable x = true, then the width must be 41vw. otherwise 38vw.

Comment: Try [ngStyle]="x?'width:41vw' : 'width:38vw'"

Answer (score 0):

`[ngStyle]="{'width': myCondition === true ? '41vw' : '38vw' }"`

Of course you can change `myCondition === true` with any condition you want.

Source on how to use ngStyle [here](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/built-in-directives/ngstyle-and-ngclass/)